# Using $\operatorname{sign}(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_k)=(-1)^{m_{1}-1}\cdot...\cdot(-1)^{m_{k}-1}$ to get the sign of the permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Given a permutation $\sigma=\sigma_1 ... \sigma_k$ (where the $\sigma_i$s are disjoint), is it true to say that its sign is:

$$\operatorname{sign}(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_k)=(-1)^{m_{1}-1}\cdot...\cdot(-1)^{m_{k}-1}$$

where $m_i$ is the length of the cycle $\sigma_i$ for every $1\leq i\leq k$ and if we get $sign(\sigma)=1$ then its even, otherwise its odd?

I tried some examples and they all satisfy this statement.

Comment: Yes. It's a special case of the identity $\operatorname{sgn}(xy)= \operatorname{sgn} x\operatorname{sgn} y$ which holds for all permutations $x,y$.

Comment: @Gae.S. I wouldn't say "special case of"; rather "follows from"